# How to fix connection to SSAS from SQL Agent?

Tags: ssis, ssas, sql-agent

I have 3 servers:
Server1 - Prod DB Server
Server2 - Prod ETL Server
Server3 - Dev Server

I created SSIS package to process cubes on nightly basis.

So Package is located on **Server2** and it uses windows authentication (impersonated user) to access SSAS db.
SQL Agent Job is also created on **Server2**.

When I setup connection in the Job Step to **Server3**(there is also SSAS db) - everything works well.

But when I setup connection to **Server1** - I get an error on job step: **"A connection cannot be made. Ensure that the server is running. "**

When I run this package manually (from file system or from Visual Studio) - it works well.

My question is: Why connection doesn't work when package is executed using SQL Agent job and works when package is executed manually?

I'll appreciate any help on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like Windows permissions - The SQL Server Agent account can't access Server 1.

Comment: Are you saying that there might be problem with permissions of SQL Agent account?

Comment: @user1390785 that's what it sounds like to me. I'd also check things like values passed to the package - Are you using configurations for DEV/PROD connection strings?